# Connect nodejs rest api to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, rest, azure

I have developed a rest api in nodejs. My database is in Azure SQL.

I have used [SWORM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sworm) npm package to connect to SQL Server.

Following is my code to connect to the Azure SQL database.

```
var conn = config.get('connectionString');
        var db = sworm.db({
            driver: 'mssql',
            config: {
                user: conn.get('user'),
                password: conn.get('password'),
                host: conn.get('host'),
                database: conn.get('database')
            }
        });
```

When I execute this code, I get following error

> "message": "Failed to connect to undefined:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433", "code": "ESOCKET"

I don't know what's wrong

Comment: It looks like your code is trying to connect to a database server hosted locally (127.0.0.1). I would recommend checking the connection string to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Yes. Why so? My connection string in config is fine, pointing to Azure sql

Comment: Do I need to make any changes to driver. Currently, I use 'mssql'.

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt - I think you missed the point Gaurav was making: Did you confirm that your connection string is correct after reading it in from the config file? That is: Did you check the value of `host`?

Comment: Yes. The connectionstring is correct. nothing wrong with it. I can connect to Azure sql database using visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Please double check the variable value of `conn`, per your error message, it was truly accessing your local MsSQL server. Please try the following code snippet for `sworm` connecting to Azure SQL Server:

```
var sworm = require('sworm');

var db = sworm.db();

db.connect({
  driver: 'mssql',
  config: {
    user: '<user>@<server>',
    password: '<password>',
    server: '<server>.database.windows.net',
    database: '<database>',
    options: {
        encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
    }
  }
}).then(()=>{
    db.query('select 1 as number').then((results)=>{
        console.log(results);
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you Gary. I tried this code to connect my local machine with Azure SQL. I got timeout exception. I have added my ip in Azure SQL's firewall exception.

Comment: the options: { encrypt: true } solved for me. Thaaaanks a lot sir.